# Sonar Server is not starting

Tags: sonarqube

[sonar.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrpTJ.jpg)

Im using Sonarqube-5.4, Java - 1.8JDK, MSSQL. It was running perfectly when initially setup and run using Jenkins builds. Suddenly it is failing, no clue why.
i have attached the log file.

Comment: @eric.hartmann - i am seeing runner error now:

Answer (score 1):

You are using Governance with SonarQube 5.4 but it's not compatible. 
So SonarQube is not starting. Since it's a commercial product, please contact the support.

Comment: that was it! thanks, its working now. Just wondering how to get daily analysis saved or shared for Sonar. Is there a plugin you would suggest?